# Help me identify these sorts of equations

Tags: calculus, integration, integral-equations

$$\int^x_0f(t)\,dt = xe^{2x}+\int^x_0e^{-t}f(t)\,dt$$
*Assume $f$ is continous*, solve for $f$.

**NB!** I'm in my first calculus course so nothing too advanced please.

---

While searching for a name for these equations I found out about *Fredholm Integral Equation of the First Kind*, which led me to a more specific type called *[Volterra integral equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra_integral_equation)*. Not very certain how they can aid me in solving this though.

I'm certain it is of the first kind as there is no mention of $f$ outside of the integral signs, and I *think* it's homogenous, for let $x=0$

$$\int^0_0f(t)\,dt = \int^0_0e^{-t}f(t)\,dt \color{red}{=0}$$

$\color{red}{*}$Red means uncertainty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Using the  [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) differentiate both sides with respect to $x$.

Note that if $g(t)$ is continuous then  the derivative of $\int_a^x g(t)\,dt$ is $g(x)$.

You will end up with an equation that is easy to solve for $f(x)$.

**Remark:** This is indeed an instance of an integral equation, but no knowledge of integral equations is required to solve the problem.

Comment: Question, do I take the derivative with respect to x or t? If I take with respect to t, my equation would state $f(t) = e^{-t}\cdot f(t)$ which means $f(t) = 0$. But if I take with respect to x, then the integral signs wouldn't differentiate, or do they in anyways?

Comment: The expression $\int_a^x g(t)\,dt$ is a function of $x$, not of $t$. You take the derivative with respect to $x$. Result is $f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(xe^{2x})+e^{-x}f(x)$.

Comment: @XMLParsing Remember The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus